# Win10 press on spacebar triggering pageDown key

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

This started happening 2 weeks backs, whenever I press spacebar in my lenovo laptop pageDown key event is getting triggered. For Enterkey pageUp-is-happening. And this is not happening always.
The wired thing is that the Enter key in my Numpad works fine.

This is what I did.

1. Removed keyboard driver and installed latest drivers
2. Reset all sticky button/ease of use settings
3. Updated windows
4. Updated all lenove drivers
5. Did antivirus and malware scan, all clean
6. Connected an external USB keyboard and <s>issue persists</s> IT WORKED, <s>(so not an hardware issue)</s>

**Update**: if-I-use-screen-keyboard I don't-have-this-issue.

**Update 2**: This is what happens when clicking the keys(taken with the help of http://en.key-test.ru/)

[image: When clicking space]

[image: On page up]

[image: On page down]

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: That is an odd issue for sure, not 100% on the cause, but I would check my Regional and Language settings and make sure I had the right keyboard layout selected.

Comment: None of my Lenovo laptops (or desktop machines for that matter) have a Keyboard driver. What keyboard driver are you using?

Comment: @John Every device has a driver, including all keyboards.

Comment: None on any of my Lenovo laptops - that is, none that the user installs.

Comment: @John my keyboard driver name is `Standard PS/2 Keyboard` and I didnt install it, it came with windows install/initial driver setup

Comment: @JimDiroffII Keyboard and regional settings are United States EN. Never did any changes here.

Comment: There is a utility called SharpKeys that allows key reassignments. I'm not suggesting you use it to fix your problem, but you might be able to use it to find the problem. It looks like SharpKeys adds registry settings that modify the keyboard button assignments. Perhaps you have something in your registry that is remapping those keys. You might be able to find the key, or change the mapping back, by using SharpKeys. Just a suggestion as I haven't run into your particular issue before.

Comment: @JimDiroffII Its a nice tool, but didnt help for me, I have updated the question with screenshots what is happening....

Comment: Have you removed the keycaps and cleaned the keyboard? Is there any evidence of detritus or liquids reaching the circuit board?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Keycaps are not removed and liquids are not involved. Only think I can remember is my kids played some games in browser and did some typing tutorial apps in chrome browser.

Comment: Update: I tried a different USB keyboard and it worked, updated the question, but the laptop issue still persists

Comment: Your OP said you tried a USB keyboard and it showed the same issue. Now you hooked up a 3rd keyboard and it does not have the issue? As described: Keyboard 1 = Laptop KB. Keyboard 2 = USB KB #1. Keyboard 3 = USB KB #2. Keyboards 1 and 2 have this issue, Keyboard 3 does not. Is that correct?

Comment: I see that you edited the OP regarding the external KB question. Now that the issue is isolated to only your laptop keyboard, I would suggest as RedGrittyBrick did that there is some type of detritus in the keyboard mesh/circuit/keycaps that is causing the mispress. That is the only time I have seen a similar issue, is when there was foreign material in between the keyboard circuit layers.

Comment: And now, after taking a closer look at your images, and seeing that your intended key is being pressed along with another, I am rather convinced now that the issue is hardware, and a good cleaning of all the keyboard related parts is in order. Pay special attention to whatever membrane or circuitry lies directly underneath the keyboard.

Comment: @JimDiroffII Yes, looks like an hardware issue of laptop (that too intermitent). I will try to clean the keyboard. Can you add your last 3 comments  as answer. I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally to the steps you have taken, check the Regional and Language settings to ensure they are correct.

Try an external keyboard to see if produces the same result.

Based on the updates in this thread, we can see that your external keyboard does not have the same issue.

This leads us to believe that you have a hardware problem with your laptop keyboard, and that fully cleaning it is the next course of action.

When cleaning the keyboard, take care to remove it completely from the laptop. Disassemble the keyboard, and remove any foreign material in between the keys and the membrane. Do it as completely as possible, so you don't have to do it twice.

After cleaning, you might also be able to connect the ribbon cable for the keyboard back to the laptop without fully installing the keyboard, so you can test it before reassembling everything.

Answer (score 0):

You did not write if this is in a specific application.
For many applications this is default behavior
spacebar is PageDown   and Shift-Spacebar is PageUp

Except for when you are in a text edit window like when you typed in this question.
If it did not show the behavior you describe there then all is ok.

Comment: This is system wide issue. This happens in browser, text editor, code editors... everywhere